# In multiplying 2 matrices, how do you know whether to operate on rows or columns?

Tags: matrices

My understanding is that multiplying a matrix by a matrix on its left means operating on rows, and multiplying a matrix by a matrix on its right means operating on columns.

When there are 2 matrices next to each other to be multiplied, how can I know whether I'm supposed to operate on columns or on rows? These 2 operations appear to produce different results.

Comment: You read a product left-to-right, so you use the rows of $A$ and the columns in $B$ to compute $AB$.  You would do the vice versa to compute $BA$.  Order matters, of course.

Comment: The columns of $AB$ are all in the column space of $A$, while its rows are all in the row space of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the product $AB$ of the $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and $n\times l$ matrix $B$ you find the dot product of row $i$ of $A$ with column $j$ of $B$ to find the $i,j$ element of the product. That is if $AB=C$ then $$c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj} $$

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will help, if we have any $3×3$ matrix $A$, and we multiply it by the permutation matrix $P_{2,3}$ from the right, here is what happens,
$$AP_{2,3}= \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
    a & c & b \\
    d & f & e \\
    g & i & h
\end{pmatrix}$$

(The second and third **columns** are switched)

Now if we multiply it by the permutation matrix $P_{2,3}$ from the left, here is what happens,
$$P_{2,3}A= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    g & h & i \\
    d & e & f
\end{pmatrix}$$

(The second and third **rows** are switched)

So $P$ works on the columns of $A$ when multiplied by $A$ from the right, and $P$ works on the rows of $A$ when multiplied by $A$ from the left.

Note that $P_{2,3}$ is the matrix obtained from the identity by flipping the second and third row (or column).

Also, $$P_{2,3}P_{2,3}= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can say that the $P_{2,3}$ on the right switched the second and the third **columns** of the $P_{2,3}$ on the left, OR you can also say that the $P_{2,3}$ on the left switched the second and third **rows** of the $P_{2,3}$ on the right.